# Advanced issues with GPU thread divergence

Tags: c++, opencl, gpgpu, nvidia, amd-processor

**My situation** - I have a dynamic programming algorithm to implement on GPUs using OpenCL as part of my PhD studies. The GPUs I am working with include AMD HD 7970, 7750, A10-5800K APU and nVidia GTX 680. I understand the principles involved and most of the best practices necessary to obtaining good performance.

My program contains 4 nested loops and in my data-parallel formulation I am able to unfold 2 of the outer loops. Now due to the nature of the problem the inner-most loop cannot do without causing divergence. The output is a table that represents schedules of jobs on machines (computer science).

When the threads diverge (work-items in a wavefront take different routes) I get wrong values, it looks as if work-items repeat themselves. For example,

t = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... **63**, 64, 65, 66, 67, ...
M1  0, 0, 0, 9, 9, ... 9,  0,  0,  0,  9,  ...

above the work-group size is 64. The first values up to t=63 are correct but notice how it repeats again at exactly t=64! They shouldn't be zeros. Here each work-item is mapped to a time t.

If I fix the parameter that causes the divergence the table gets completely filled with the expected (wrong) results, no gaps (zeros), so I get value 9 from t=0 up to TMAX, where TMAX is a multiple of 64.

**QUESTION** - Does thread divergence have the tendency of resulting in wrong calculations or undefined thread behavior?

I have dug the internet, documentations, books on anything I can find about thread divergence and memory consistency. I have implemented the whole program in different ways including one that calls the kernel multiple times so as to rule out global memory inconsistency but the results are all the same.

Any input will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, I'm ashamed to admit this here, but one of the computation conditions was giving wrong values and so it looked like work-items were acting strange which they weren't. Problem corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is simple: You are supossing the first 64 threads will run and finish before the next 64 threads. That is NOT true, all of them run in parallel.

In fact you have to suppose as baseline that all your GLOBAL workgroup size will run in parallel or even in a non-deterministic order (from the end to beggining).
The only constrain the user can put to a kernel execution in that each chunck of threads (local workgroup size) will run at the same time. This aids the sharing the intermediate results internally or sharing the memory accesses.

In your case, if the local workgroup uses a global memory as starting point, then the first 64 threads workgroup and the second one will produce the same results.

Please revise your code/algorithm to do it really parallel. A paste from your kernel code will also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks very much for the input. I understand what you are trying to explain especially since I am dealing with dynamic programming. Each intermediate result is calculated GLOBALLY because it can be done in parallel so the NDRange is fine :)